# Remove part of absolute path string

Tags: linux, perl, sed

In Linux, I'm trying to remove part of a path in a text file. The full path is:

> \server/glb/data/dir/var/loc2/log/123456.log

I am trying to simply remove glb/data/ from the string to give me:

> \server/dir/var/loc2/log/123456.log

I have been trying to used sed and perl to no avail.
This will be inserted into a script running to create the link and insert it into an Oracle table.

There are other links within the test file, so I don't think the cut command will work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show us the sed or perl code which failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some bash that should work with sed:

```
file_name='\server/glb/data/dir/var/loc2/log/123456.log'
echo $file_name | sed -e 's,glb/data/,,'
```

that will print the stripped path, to save it in a var

```
new_name=$(echo $file_name | sed -e 's,glb/data/,,')
```

Similarly in perl you can do

```
my $file_name='\server/glb/data/dir/var/loc2/log/123456.log';
$file_name =~ s,glb/data/,,;
```

Comment: The sed command worked, great. Thank you. What is the significance of the commas at the end of the command?

Comment: Sed uses a delimiter to break it's command pieces into segments, the `glb/data/` in this case being the pattern to match, and the empty string being the pattern to replace the matched pattern with.  It's mostly typical to use `/` as the delimiter, but since `/` shows up in the pattern we're trying to match, I used `,` instead.  sed actually doesn't much care what you use, but `,` is my first choice when I don't want to use `/`

Answer (score 1):

This seems straightforward:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

use feature qw(say);

my $path = '\server/glb/data/dir/var/loc2/log/123456.log'
say $path =~ s|/glb/data||gr; 
# \server/dir/var/loc2/log/123456.log
```

The above can be subject to failure depending on your platform. The below is a safer way to perform this operation:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

use English qw(-no_match_vars);
use feature qw(say);
use File::Basename;

sub remove_dirs_from_path { 
   my ( $path, @to_remove ) = @_; 
   my $path_separator = $OSNAME =~ m/MSWin32/ ? '\\' : '/';

   my ($filename, $directory, undef) = fileparse($path);

   my @dirs_to_keep;
   foreach my $dir ( split $path_separator, $directory ) {
      next if grep { $dir eq $_ } @to_remove;

      push @dirs_to_keep, $dir;
   }

   return join($path_separator, @dirs_to_keep, $filename);
}

say remove_dirs_from_path(
       '\server/glb/data/dir/var/loc2/log/123456.log', 
       qw(glb data)
    );
```